# Unable to remap evil key bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

I am new to emacs and I have been trying to remap some of the keys inside of evil mode. I have been trying to remap the keys for switching between windows and so far I have had no luck.

```
(use-package evil
   :config 
   (evil-mode 1)

   (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
   (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
   (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)
   (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
(defun evil()

  (require 'evil)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-h") nil)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-j") nil)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-k") nil)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-l") nil)

  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-top)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)

  (evil-mode 1))
```

You could also use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) for this instead of using `require`

Answer (score 1):

Try bind.

```
(use-package evil
  :bind (:map evil-motion-state-map
              ("C-j" . evil-window-down)
              ("C-k" . evil-window-up)
              ("C-l" . evil-window-right)
              ("C-h" . evil-window-left)))
```

Update:

```lisp
(use-package evil
:bind ((:map evil-window-map
             ("C-j" . evil-window-down)
             ("C-k" . evil-window-up)
             ("C-l" . evil-window-right)
             ("C-h" . evil-window-left))
       (:map evil-normal-state-map
             ("C-j" . evil-window-down)
             ("C-k" . evil-window-up)
             ("C-l" . evil-window-right)
             ("C-h" . evil-window-left)))
:config (evil-mode 1))
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: Ah, according to [docs](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keymaps.html#keymaps) evil’s key bindings are stored in a number of different keymaps so you may also need to bind the other ones, such as evil-normal-state-map, evil-insert-state-map and so on. `  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C l") 'evil-window-left)`

Comment: I have tried updates code that you have provided and so far all of the keybindings work except for C-l.